# GregwarCaptchaBundle: TextType could not been loaded

Tags: php, symfony, captcha

I'm using the gregwarCaptchaBundle in my project and I got the following error message: `Could not load type "Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType"`

Details:

```
 at FormRegistry ->getType ('Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType')
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormRegistry.php at line 121  +
at FormRegistry ->resolveAndAddType (object(CaptchaType))
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormRegistry.php at line 86  +
at FormRegistry ->getType ('captcha')
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.php at line 82  +
at FormFactory ->createNamedBuilder ('captcha', 'captcha', null, array('distortion' => false, 'reload' => true, 'as_url' => true, 'humanity' => '1000'))
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilder.php at line 106  +
at FormBuilder ->create ('captcha', 'captcha', array('distortion' => false, 'reload' => true, 'as_url' => true, 'humanity' => '1000'))
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilder.php at line 267  +
at FormBuilder ->resolveChildren ()
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilder.php at line 215  +
at FormBuilder ->getForm ()
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.php at line 39  +
at FormFactory ->create (object(RatingForm), null, array())
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php at line 250  +
at Controller ->createForm (object(RatingForm))
in vendor/xxBundle/RatingBundle/pp/RatingBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php at line 63  +
at DefaultController ->renderRatingInterfaceAction (object(Request), 'Profil', '3209', true, false, true, '5')
    ...
```

The code of the formtype is this:

```
<?php


    ...

    public function setUser($user) {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function setSession($session) {
        if (!is_null($session)) {
            $sessionBlocked = $session->get(sprintf('gcb_%s', 'captcha') . '_humanity');
            $this->sessionBlocked = $sessionBlocked;
        }
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        //$user = $builder->getData()->getUser();

        $builder->setMethod('post');
        $builder->setAction('');
        $builder->add('commenctcontent', 'textarea', array(
            'required' => true,
        ))
        ->add('name','text',array(
            'required' => true,
        ))
        ->add('email','text',array(
            'required' => true,
        ));

        if(!is_object($this->user)){
            $options = array(
                'distortion'    => false,
                'reload'        => true,
                'as_url'        => true,
                'humanity'      => 1000,
            );
            $builder->add('captcha', 'captcha', $options);
        }

        $builder->add('starratevalue','hidden');

    }
    ...
}
```

Can't find any mistake or wrong code. The mysterious is: I'm using exactly the same code in another project. In this other project, it works really fine.

Comment: What version of Symfony and the bundle are you using?

Comment: seems the support for the sf >=2.8 for bundle you are using is working in progress (i suppose you are using a sf3 version) try to point to the dev-master in the composer json. on github i see the issue for the sf3 compatibility is not yet closed but you can try

Comment: if you are using a sf version <2.8 use the version taged as 1.1

Comment: I'm using sf 2.7.* and the bundle version "dev-master" (from composer.json)

Comment: so try the tagged version 1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just upgraded to symfony version 2.8 and it works! :)

Answer (score 3):

The GregwarCaptchaBundle is trying to load the base type for the captcha form type by its fully qualified class name. This is a feature that was added in Symfony 2.8 and is the default in 3.0. With [this commit](https://github.com/Gregwar/CaptchaBundle/commit/52107b0c32cfe6bc18ca237e41257751007558d8#diff-ffb1dde7f65b56a893ee369f2a4bd806), the bundle was made Symfony 3.0 compatible, but Symfony 2.7 incompatible. Using version v1.0.12 instead of version v1.0.13 should fix the problem.

**EDIT:** [Following some discussion](https://github.com/Gregwar/CaptchaBundle/issues/148#issuecomment-163880048) in the issue queue of the bundle. The author has removed the v.1.0.13 tag and added a v2.0 tag. The new compatibility information states:

- If you are using Symfony < 2.8 or PHP < 5.5, you should use version 1.*
- If you are using Symfony >= 2.8 and PHP >= 5.5, you should use version 2.*